CORS error on Azure Storage calls from Javascript to commit chunked uploads
I want users to upload a huge file directly into Azure Storage. I have a Flask Python web app but I do not want the file to be uploaded into my web server due to size constraints.
When the user has selected the file they want to upload and clicks the upload button, the following happens:

An API is called that generates a SAS URL and a blob name to assign to the file to be uploaded. The code that generates both is:

    blob_name = str(uuid.uuid4())  

    container_name = os.environ[default_container_name_setting]

    sas = generate_blob_sas(account_name=service.account_name,
                            account_key=access_key,
                            container_name=container_name,
                            blob_name=blob_name,
                            permission=BlobSasPermissions(write=True, read=True, create=True),
                            expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=2)) 

    sas_url = 'https://' + service.account_name + '.blob.core.windows.net/' + container_name + '/' + blob_name + '?' + sas
    return sas_url, blob_name


The file is then uploaded in chunks via Javascript:

const chunkSize = 1024 * 1024 * 20; 
const totalChunks = Math.ceil(file.size / chunkSize);
const blockIds = []; // Array to hold block IDs

for (let i = 0; i < totalChunks; i++) {
    const start = i * chunkSize;
    const end = Math.min(start + chunkSize, file.size);
    const chunk = file.slice(start, end);
    const blockId = btoa("block-" + i); // Base64 encode block ID
    blockIds.push(blockId);

    // Upload each chunk
    const uploadResponse = await fetch(sas_url + "&comp=block&blockid=" + blockId, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
            "Content-Type": file.type
        },
        body: chunk
    });

    if (!uploadResponse.ok) {
        return false;
    }
}

It works up to this point. However, the next step is to tell Azure to put the chunks together, still via Javascript:
const commitResponse = await fetch(sas_url + "&comp=commitBlockList", {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/xml",
        "x-ms-version": "2020-10-02",
        "Content-Length": "0"
    },
    body: `<BlockList>${blockIds.map(id => `<Latest>${id}</Latest>`).join('')}</BlockList>`
});

if (!commitResponse.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to commit blocks to blob.");
}

I always get a CORS error at this point:

Access to fetch at 'https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/container/e07d13fa-bcd6-45cf-9eea-3295e17dc567?se=2024-11-01T04%2A18%3B30Q&sp=rcw&sv=2024-11-04&sr=b&sig=Cudr...&comp=commitBlockList' from origin 'http://localhost:4449' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I know I have properly set the CORS in Azure Storage because the upload part works.
Under Blob Service tab, I have added my localhost origin, with allowed methods GET, POST, OPTIONS, and PUT.
I have tried regenerating another SAS Url with the retrieved Blob name but I'm still getting the CORS error.
What am I missing?
Update: I have narrowed down the CORS error to the query string "&comp=commitBlockList" added to the SAS URL in the commit step. I still don't know how to resolve it, though.

Have to added cors in backend code

I have edited my question to make it clear that my calls to Azure are done via Javascript. I'm not sure how adding CORS to my backend code will help? Unless I'm missing your point @Sampath

#1 Invoke the last request (put chunks together) with postman or similar tool and share the result in your question.  #2 Sometimes in the background there is another error but the load balancers causes a CORS error.

@rikitikitik Check the below answer.

I don't think the problem is related to CORS because if it were CORS related, you would have received an error when uploading chunks (both PUT BLOCK and PUT BLOCK LIST operations are Put requests.
I believe the issue is with your block ids. According to the documentation, the block ids must be of the same length. Considering your are adding the chunk index to get the block id, after 10th chunk, your block id length will be different.
Try to keep the length of block ids same. You can use GUID as the block id or prefix your counter with some zeros in order to keep the same length for the block id.

I have already addressed the block id lengths as that was one of the first errors I encountered while uploading the blocks. I have padded the block ids with leading 0s to get around this limitation. And I'm still getting the CORS error.


I want users to upload a huge file directly into Azure Storage. I have a Flask Python web app but I do not want the file to be uploaded into my web server due to size constraints.

In my environment, I set the CORS  to the storage account like below.
To enable CORS in Azure blob storage:
Portal -> Your storage account -> Under setting(Resource sharing CORS) -> blobs service.
Allowed origins = *
Allowed methods = GET, HEAD, MERGE, DELETE, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH (For your environments it is better to add only the required methods)
Allowed headers= *
Exposed headers= *
Max age = 86400

Portal:

In my environment, I created sample flask app with python and index.html.
app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.storage.blob import generate_blob_sas, BlobSasPermissions

app = Flask(__name__)

# Replace these values with your Azure Storage account details
account_name = "venkat326123"
account_key = "xxxx"
container_name = "result"

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/get_sas_token', methods=['GET'])
def get_sas_token():
    blob_name = request.args.get("blob_name")
    if not blob_name:
        return jsonify({"error": "blob_name is required"}), 400

    # Generate a SAS token
    sas_token = generate_blob_sas(
        account_name=account_name,
        container_name=container_name,
        blob_name=blob_name,
        account_key=account_key,
        permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True, write=True, create=True, add=True),
        expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
    )
    
    url = f'https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}?{sas_token}'
    return jsonify({"sas_url": url})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Upload File to Azure Blob Storage</h1>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" />
    <button onclick="uploadFile()">Upload</button>

    <script>
       async function uploadFile() {
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    const file = fileInput.files[0];
    if (!file) {
        alert('Please select a file to upload.');
        return;
    }

    // Request SAS token from the Flask backend
    const response = await fetch(`/get_sas_token?blob_name=${file.name}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    if (!response.ok) {
        alert(`Error: ${data.error}`);
        return;
    }

    const sasUrl = data.sas_url;
    const chunkSize = 8 * 1024 * 1024; // 8 MB
    const totalChunks = Math.ceil(file.size / chunkSize);
    const blockList = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < totalChunks; i++) {
        const start = i * chunkSize;
        const end = Math.min(start + chunkSize, file.size);
        const chunk = file.slice(start, end);

        // Generate fixed-length block ID (e.g., "000001", "000002")
        const blockId = btoa(String(i).padStart(6, '0')); // Base64 encode to make it URL-safe
        blockList.push(blockId);

        // Stage block
        await fetch(`${sasUrl}&comp=block&blockid=${encodeURIComponent(blockId)}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: chunk,
            headers: {
                'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob'
            }
        });
    }

    // Commit block list
    const blockListXml = `
        <BlockList>
            ${blockList.map(blockId => `<Latest>${blockId}</Latest>`).join('')}
        </BlockList>
    `;
    await fetch(`${sasUrl}&comp=blocklist`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: blockListXml,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
        }
    });

    alert('File uploaded successfully!');
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Output:

Portal:

